# Acer Timeline X 3830TG Battery life

Tags: 11.10, battery, acer

i'm running ubuntu 11.10 and i'm interested in getting more life out of my battery,

I see a lot of people adding extra lines to their /etc/default/grub file after "quiet splash".

For instance one user suggested

change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to be:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=Linux i915.i915_enable_rc6=1″

This was for his Acer Aspire Timelinex AS4830tg-6450,

The hardware of the 4830TG differ only by the processor, his is the intel core i5-2430M 2.3Ghz while mine is the intel core i5-2410M 2.3Ghz

Are these changes model/hardware specific.

What changes should i make to get the same results (he noticed a big increase in battery life)

anything else i can do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the power regression and overheating bug affected most Intel processors including the Core 2 Duo, i3, i5 (sandy bridge). The fix that you rightly pointed out will surely boost your battery life. The Kernel update for 11.10 might include these tweaks. From the feedback on this Grub tweak it seems it works so go ahead and make the changes

Comment: Seems to work. Battery life just jumped up by an hour. Yippie!!

Comment: Did the notebook overheat prior to the tweaks and if it did is the notebook cooler now?

Comment: Never overheated. temp seems to be about the same. Can't give you a precise answer because i didn't take those readings before the switch.

Comment: Ok seems you were only affected by the power regression bug. Is battery life better now

Answer (score 0):

This fix mentioned here worked well for my 11.10 installation on an Acer Timelinex 3830T-6870.

Battery life up as much as 3hrs. This gives it comparable values to battery life it gets in windows

powertop readings indicated usage as low as 8.5W, whereas before this fix it got to 11.3W as the lowest. No other issues have been caused by the grub edit.